# selenium phantomjs span tags not showing

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

Running phantomjs in java has given me a headache.   When I run the program and getpagesource I'm able to extract the a->src attributes the ul->li text but NOT inside the SPAN tag.   This may be due to masking or incorrect css.   The JS script is in angular.

My selected console output after I call driver.getPageSource() is (notice property-address is empty):

```
     <div class="propertylist-property-details col-lg-6">
            <a href="/property-detail/gblhrdlad152749">
                <span class="property-name ng-binding" ng-bind="data.AddressLine1"></span>
                <span class="property-address ng-binding" ng-bind="data.AddressLine2"></span>
            </a>


                <!-- ngIf:  -->

            <span class="property-bullets">
                <ul>
                        <li>- Grade II listed facade </li>
                        <li>- Exposed concrete beams </li>
                        <li>- Italian kitchens </li>
                        <li>- Underfloor heating and comfort cooling </li>
                        <li>1054 Sq.Feet (97.92 Sq.Metres) </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </div>
```

My java code is following:

```
     public static synchronized void testPhantomDriver() throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);  
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:\\location of \\phantomjs.exe");
    String oldpage=""; String newpage="";       
    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
     try{
    driver.get("http://search.savills.com/property-detail/gbcsrdlad140551#/r/list/property-for-sale%252Fengland%252Fbristol%252Fbristol%252Fbs1%252Fgbp");



    WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl_GRS_PT_ND\"]")); // the trigger event element

    Actions build = new Actions(driver); //  ActionBuider
    build.moveToElement(menu).build().perform(); //  perform hover mouse over the needed element to triger visibility
    build.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();

       driver.findElement(By.id("ViewAll")).click();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       System.out.println("clicked");
       //driver = scrollToBottom(driver, 2000);
       try{
           System.out.println("waiting");
           driver.wait(4000);
       }catch(InterruptedException ie){
           System.out.println("iexception: " + ie);
       }
       System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());       
}catch(Exception exp){
    System.out.println("exception:" + exp);
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}  
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
/**
 * Main method
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // run webdriver
        testPhantomDriver();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("exception");
    }
}
```

Some solutions I have been thinking that you might help with? (1) load as iframe (2) or wait for complete page load.  I have tried reading the page in Jsoup using connect(url).get() but the visibility again is hidden.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

Try the firefoxdriver and chromedriver instead of phantomjs.exe.  Uses more memory but at least you get all the data.